# Bind class instance for partially applied functions

Tags: monads, purescript

The definition of the `Bind` class in the Prelude is:

```
class Apply m <= Bind m where
  bind :: forall a b. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

It can be read as a function taking *two* input parameters, a value in a monadic context (`m a`) and a function (`a -> m b`) and returning a value in a monadic context (`m b`).

The instance of `Bind` for partially-applied function is defined as:

```
instance bindFn :: Bind ((->) r) where
  bind m f x = f (m x) x
```

Which is a function taking *three* parameters. How does that typecheck?

If I try to replace `m a` by a more concrete type I get (correct me if I am wrong):

```
(((->) ??) a) -> (a -> (((->) ??) b)) -> (((->) ??) b)
```

which is equivalent to

```
(?? -> a) -> (a -> (?? -> b)) -> (?? -> b)
```

Assuming the variable `m` is bound to `(?? -> a`), `f` would get bound to `a -> ?? -> b`, and `x` to the second `??`.

Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to what swizard said (which is correct), one way to check what the type signature of a type class function is once it's been specialized to a particular instance is to write it out and see if psci agrees:

```
> :type bind :: forall r a b. (r -> a) -> (a -> r -> b) -> (r -> b)
forall r a b. (r -> a) -> (a -> r -> b) -> r -> b
```

So your reasoning is indeed correct. If we'd written out an incorrect type, we would have been given a type error:

```
> :type bind :: forall r. r -> r
Error found:
[...]
   Could not match type [...] with [...]
[...]
```

Also, just in case you weren't already aware, the function type constructor `->` is right-associative, so `a -> (r -> b)` is the same as `a -> r -> b`.

Answer (score 6):

> Which is a function taking three parameters. How does that typecheck?

As far as I know, in current context this function signature:

```
bind m f x = f (m x) x
```

should be equal to just:

```
bind m f = \x -> f (m x) x
```